# Does the EU 261 regulation applicable to Widerøe traveling inside Norway?

Tags: air-travel, norway, ec261

Widerøe is a Norwegian company operating inside Norway and closes by regions. Does the EU 261 regulation applicable to it when canceled and traveling within Norway? The question arises from the fact that Norway is a non-EU country.

If not EU 261 what regulations apply then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst Norway is not a member of the European Union, they are part of a [Bilateral Agreement](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:22015D1481&from=EN) with the EU regarding air transportation.  As a result of this, EU261 DOES apply to Norwegian airlines.

This can be confirmed on the main EU [Air Passenger Rights](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm) website, which states :

> EU means the 28 EU countries , including Guadeloupe, French Guiana,
>   Martinique, Réunion Island, Mayotte, Saint-Martin (French Antilles),
>   the Azores, Madeira and the Canary Islands **as well as Iceland, Norway
>   and Switzerland**. It does not include the Faeroe Islands, the Isle of
>   Man and the Channel Islands.

So yes, flights within Norway by Widerøe ARE covered by EU261.